# I have a list with Incident numbers. I want to run a test case for each of the incident. How to pass the values from list into Cucumber feature file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber, gherkin

I have a list with Incident numbers. I want to run a test case for each of the incident. I get the list from an excel file during execution. How to pass the values from list into Cucumber feature file?

Comment: https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline

Comment: What is an "Incident" and "Incident numbers"? What have you tried so far? I suggest sharing the related code so people can understand better your situation.